# File Rename pytesting with mocker.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a function to rename file in my directory and save as a new file. I have done it the following way.

```
def function(input_d):
   for file in os.listdir(input_d):
       if file.startswith('copy_'):
          new_file = file.split("_")[-1]
          os.rename(os.path.join(input_d,file),os.path.join(input_d,new_file))
   return input_d
```

I want to use `mocker.patch` to test my function but I have just started with pytest and unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, if you want to test that the files are renamed, you have to somehow record the renames. This can be done by mocking `os.rename` with a function that does this. Also, `os.listdir` has to be mocked to return the needed values. Here is an example implementation:

```py
import os

from your_module.sut import function

def test_rename(mocker):
    renames = {}

    def fake_rename(old, new):
        renames[old] = new

    mocker.patch("os.listdir", return_value=("foo.txt", "copy_bar.txt"))
    mocker.patch("os.rename", fake_rename)
    function("my_dir")
    assert len(renames) == 1
    old_path = os.path.join("my_dir", "copy_bar.txt")
    assert old_path in renames
    assert renames[old_path] == os.path.join("my_dir", "bar.txt")
```

Note that the test itself is not sufficient (what happens if the file already exists?), but that is up to you.

Another approach for testing is to use a fake filesystem (a file system that is created in memory). This generally makes sense if you are testing many filesystem related functionality. If using the `fs` fixture provided by [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/4.5.1/), the same test could look something like this:

```py
import os

from your_module.sut import function

def test_rename(fs):
    fs.create_file("my_dir/foo.txt")
    fs.create_file("my_dir/copy_bar.txt")
    function("my_dir")
    assert os.path.exists("my_dir/foo.txt")
    assert os.path.exists("my_dir/bar.txt")
```

*Disclaimer*:
I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.